# Google Play Store doesn't auto update apps on my Motorola Moto G

Tags: google-play-store, motorola-moto-g, application-autoupdate

I have a German retail Motorola Moto G (2013) running Android 4.4.4 stock, no root. I have the Google Play Store not auto updating my apps despite it being set to do so (over Wifi only). I tried everything I could think of: I re-flashed the stock image, I deleted the Play Store cache and data, I removed my Google account from the phone, I deleted the Google Play Services data and cache and updated it. Nothing. If I boot my phone with the Wifi on sometimes it auto updates apps. If I boot it with the Wifi turned off and I turn it on after say 3 minutes it doesn't ever auto update. It's like some process which exists at the beginning then crashes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when Google Play Store auto update doesn't work, just running the Play Store once, that should get all pending updates by itself.

Comment: I tried that too. Right now, for example I have an update for Temple Run 2. It's in the Google Play Store. I know because I launched the Store and looked under My Apps section. But it does nothing. It just sits there. I re-checked my setting in the Play Store and apps are still set to auto update over Wifi.